# In Mongodb, how do I add a field to every record?

Tags: mongodb, database

I want to add the field "bio" to "about" section of the document.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose that you're using mongo console.
To add a field to each document in a collection you have to use this command:

```
db.foo.update({},{$set : { "about.bio" : ""}} , true, true);
```

Of course you have to replace `foo` with your real collection name. This command use empty string (`""`) as default value for the new field: you can change this behaviour changing the value in the command.

Hope this helps

Comment: I would be using upsert set false

Comment: You can also use `db.foo.updateMany({},{$set : { "about.bio" : ""}});`

Answer (score 1):

Adding a field to each document in a collection in cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin
mongo
use yourdb
db.yourcollection.update({}, {$set:{"new_field":"value"}}, false, true)
```

This example is made for MongoDB 4.2